ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 library - is there a way to ignore invalid SAML signatures?
I'm using the ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 library to add SSO to a service.
I have a use-case where I'd like to ignore errors caused by expired certificates when accepting SAML requests. At the moment I get an exception, "Signature is invalid".
Is this possible? If so, how?  I've had a look through the library's source and can see there are some signature-checking methods that take a "bool validate" parameter, but I've not been able to figure out if it's ultimately possible to do what I want via the API.

The signature is not validated on read where the "bool validate" parameter is used. The signature validation can not be disabled or changed. Unless you make some code changes.
